symplectic form on $\mathbb{P}^n\mathbb{C}$
I'd like to show that the standard symplectic form $\tilde{\omega} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n+1} dx^i \wedge dy^i$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ (with $x^i + iy^i = z^i \in \mathbb{C}$) induces a 2-form on $\mathbb{P}^n\mathbb{C}$. This is what I tried: one can write $T_z\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \cong \mathbb{R} z \ \oplus \ z^{\perp}$ and the restriction of $d\pi_z$ to $z^{\perp}$ is an isomorphism. Hence, if we define $\omega_{[z]}(v_1,v_2) = \tilde{\omega}_z(w_1,w_2)$, with $d\pi_z(w_i) = v_i$, I was hoping to prove that when $w_1 = w_1'+kz$ and $w_2 = w_2' + hz$ then $\tilde{\omega}(w_1,w_2) = \tilde{\omega}(w_1',w_2')$. Clearly, $\tilde{\omega}(z,z) = 0$, but I can't understand how to go on from here. Any help?

Can you please clarify (i) How this differs from your earlier question and/or (ii) Why the answers there didn't help?

The answers there gave me a great help! Unfortunately I wasn't able to conclude, hence I'm asking here what I'm missing from the answers to that post in order to hopefully conclude :) .

Your best bet is to view $\omega$ is the imaginary part of the Hermitian form on $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, the real part being the Riemannian metric $g$.  The simple relation between them is $\omega(X,Y)=g(JX,Y)$, where $J$ is the complex structure satisfying $J^2=-1$.  Working with the metric is often more convenient because one can view it as a quadratic form of a single variable (instead of two), via the polarisation formula.  At any rate, the existence of the 2-form is equivalent to the existence of the metric.  To construct the metric, you restrict the metric on $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ to the complement of $\mathbb C\,z$ where $z$ is a point.  The metrics are defined in such a way that this metric maps isometrically to the metric of $\mathbb CP^n$.  In other words, you can actually define the metric on the complex projective space this way, and with it also the 2-form by the procedure I described above.
